# приложение собранное на py2exe не записывает данные

Tags: python, python-2.x, exe, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь собрать приложение с помощью   py2exe

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

url = 'http://www.autobody.ru/kuzovnoy-remont/'
urls=['http://www.autobody.ru/kuzovnoy-remont/','http://www.autobody.ru/optics/','http://www.autobody.ru/tuning/','http://www.autobody.ru/cooling/','http://www.autobody.ru/mechanics/','http://www.autobody.ru/mirrors/']
for url in urls:
 html = get_html(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
 mydivs = soup.findAll('a',class_="banners_images")
 urls = []

 for i in mydivs:
    ur = (i.get('href'))
    ur = 'http://www.autobody.ru' + str(ur)
    urls.append(ur)

 images = []
 heads = []
 artic = []
 atrib = []
 price = []

 with open('c:\\1\\1.csv', 'a') as f:        # Open the file in binary mode for Python 2.x
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # writes "byte order mark" UTF-8 signature
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for i in urls:
        html = get_html(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        head = soup.find('h1').get_text()
        heads.append(head.encode('utf8'))

        image = [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'detimg'})]
        image1 = 'http://www.autobody.ru'+image[0]
        images.append(image1.encode('utf8'))

        price1 = soup.find('div', class_='price').get_text()
        price1 = re.sub(r"c",r"p", price1)
        price.append(price1.encode('utf8'))

        for tr in soup.find('table', class_='tech').find_all('tr'):
            artic.append(tr.get_text().strip().encode('utf8'))

        for i in range (0, len(artic)):
          if 'Артикул' in artic[i]:
              atrib.append(artic[i])
        writer.writerows(zip(*[heads, price, atrib, images]))
```

Я собрал приложение выполнив следующий код : python setup.py py2exe
.Когда запускаю ехe файл создается , но не наполняется  , если запускать код с локалки  питона все  отлично работает и файл заполняется .Лог файл не создается при этом.

Comment: Что значит "файл заполняется" ?

Comment: данные которые спарсены записываются в файл